# Is it possible to combine instances of a typeclass?

Tags: haskell

I have a feeling this isn't possible, but would love some input to see if there's some extensions or techniques I'm missing.

I have a generic instance of a typeclass that defines some default methods:

```
class TestClass a where 
  foo :: a -> Maybe Text 
  bar :: a -> [Int]

instance TestClass a where 
  foo _ = Nothing 
  bar _ = []

data SpecificType = SomeValue | OtherValue

instance TestClass SpecificType where 
  foo SomeValue = Just "Success"
  foo OtherValue = Just "Other Success"
```

I believe this already needs `OverlappingInstances`, but the problem is that the instance of `TestClass` for `SpecificType` doesn't implement `bar`. I'd like to only declare a part of the second instance, and use the default implementation for the rest. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell 98, you can **put [default implementations](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#class-default-signatures) in the `class` definition**:

```
class TestClass a where
    foo :: a -> Maybe Text 
    foo _ = Nothing  -- default implementation
    bar :: a -> [Int]
    bar _ = []       -- default implementation
```

Now for all `instance`s where you do not implement `foo` or `bar` yourself, it will take the default implementation.

Comment: Are there any other ways to combine instances? Admittedly, my use case is more complex than what I presented. For example, what if the default instance also requires `Show`? (`instance Show a => TestClass a where ...`

Comment: @jkeuhlen well, ask a more specific question then.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I probably will, but I also learned something from this answer and it is helpful to the question as asked, so I'm not just going to edit my current question or ask a new one without first following up here.

Comment: @jkeuhlen `DefaultSignatures` allows you to declare a default with a type that is more specific. [See `aeson` for an example](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/08fcbcd6ed65d9b3d80300e2bd363bfcd76e38bd/Data/Aeson/Types/ToJSON.hs#L284)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That's exactly what I'm looking for thanks! If you'd like to add an answer, or edit it into WillemVanOnsem's answer (with approval) I think it deserves to be at a higher level than a comment. Thanks! It's in the link in the main answer already, but you have to look for it. I didn't realize that extension even existed.